# VBScript OpenTextFile File Not Found error when Windows Explorer shows the file

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a program in VBScript to automate the process of file encryption, and am struggling with a problem.

I want to test which code the script will execute based on whether a file comparison returns an errorlevel of 0 or 1. (For simplicity, I cut out that code from this post.) Google searches have pointed me to the following to start the process of modifying one of the comparison files for this purpose.

```
Set testFile = fso.OpenTextFile(testDestFile, 8, False, 0)
```

However, VBScript always throws a "File not found" error for that line unless I put

```
WScript.Echo "testDestFile is '" & testDestFile & "'..."
```

right before it.

I don't want that, because the script's actions should be invisible to the user unless necessary. When I run this script, I can see in Windows Explorer that it creates the file represented by `testDestFile`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Dim baseDirLen, compareOpts, decryptOpts, destDataPath, destFolder, _
   destFolderPath, encDestFile, encryptorPath, encryptOpts, file, fileName, _
   folder, folderEnd, fso, keyPath, oShell, srcDataPath, srcDirEndLen, _
   srcFolder, strErrorCode, testDestFile, testDiff, testFile, t

Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
srcDataPath = "e:\EZcrypt\TargetData"
keyPath = "e:\EZcrypt\Key\Demo010719.key.bin"
destDataPath = "E:\EZcrypt\EncryptedData"
encryptorPath = "E:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl"

Set srcFolder = fso.GetFolder(srcDataPath)
baseDirLen = Len(srcDataPath)

recurseFolders(srcFolder)

Sub recurseFolders(srcFolder)
    For Each folder In srcFolder.subfolders
        srcDirEndLen = (Len(folder) - baseDirLen - 1)
        folderEnd = Right(folder, srcDirEndLen)
        destFolderPath = destDataPath & "\" & folderEnd & "\"

        If Not fso.FolderExists(destFolderPath) Then
            fso.CreateFolder(destFolderPath)
        End If

        For Each file In folder.Files
            fileName = fso.GetFileName(file)
            testDestFile = destFolderPath & "test." & fileName
            encDestFile = destFolderPath & fileName & ".enc"

            If Not fso.FileExists(encDestFile) Then
                strErrorCode = ""
                encryptOpts = encryptorPath & " enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in """ & _
                              file & """ -out """ & encDestFile & _
                              """ -pass file:""" & keyPath & """ -pbkdf2"
                oShell.Run (encryptOpts)
                decryptOpts = encryptorPath & " enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in """ & _
                              encDestFile & """ -out """ & testDestFile & _
                              """ -pass file:""" & keyPath & """ -pbkdf2"
                oShell.Run (decryptOpts)
                WEcript.Echo "testDestFile is '" & testDestFile & "'..."
                Set testFile = fso.OpenTextFile(testDestFile, 8, False, 0)                    
            Else
                WScript.Echo "'" & encDestFile & "' exists. Skipping..."
            End If
        Next
        recurseFolders(folder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason for the behavior you observed is that the `openssl` commands you run right before trying to open that file (specifically the encryption command, which appears to be creating the file) haven't finished yet. You don't tell the [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky%28v%3dvs.85%29) method to wait for the commands to return, so they're running asynchronously in the background. Presumably the `WScript.Echo` adds just enough delay for the encryption to finish before the code proceeds to opening the file. Using `WScript.Sleep` instead of echoing something would probably have had the same effect.

To fix the issue, wait for the external commands to return.

Replace these lines:

```
encryptOpts = encryptorPath & ...
oShell.Run (encryptOpts)
decryptOpts = encryptorPath & ...
oShell.Run (decryptOpts)
```

with this:

```
encryptOpts = encryptorPath & ...
oShell.Run encryptOpts, 0, True
decryptOpts = encryptorPath & ...
oShell.Run decryptOpts, 0, True
```

It's also good practice to check the exit status of external commands, so you can see if something went wrong:

```
rc = oShell.Run(encryptOpts, 0, True)
If rc <> 0 Then
    'an error occurred
End If
```

Comment: That was a huge help, thank you. (Unfortunately, my Reputation isn't high enough yet for my upvote to count.) Also, thank you for the pointer about the external command exit status.